# ternary conditional statements using eval

Tags: asp.net, conditional-statements, eval, ternary-operator

I'm trying to make a ternary conditional statement using eval. However I do not know how to make it since I need to output an asp link or an asp label.

This is my unfinished ternary condition:

```
  <%# Eval("TaggedActive") == 0 ? %>

// <asp:LinkButton Text="Button" OnClick="function" runat="server" />

<%# : %>

// <asp:Label Text="Already Clicked"  runat="server" />
```

How do I write my condition?

Comment: I actually realized that I can just use a Visible attribute to control both of the fields so if it is true it will show and if not it will not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that I just need to put this on both my fields, but I had to reverse the condition so It won't show at the same time.

```
Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TaggedActive")) == 0 ? true : false %>'
```